# Add Percentages to Categorical Counts in rtables for Table 1 in a Clinical Trial Report

Tags: r

For "Table 1" (Baseline subject characteristics) in a clinical trial paper, I would like to include percentages for each level of a categorical variable.  The rtables package is otherwise producing what I want.

Based on the vignette at https://rdrr.io/cran/rtables/f/vignettes/clinical_trials.Rmd, the default output lists counts for each level:

```
require(rtables)
set.seed(6502)
SubjChar<-data.frame(
    USUBJID=c(101:200),
    TREATMENT=as.factor(sample(c("Placebo", "Drug A", "Drug B"), 100, replace=TRUE)),
    AGE=c(rnorm(100)*5+30),
    HEIGHT=c(rnorm(100)*20+180),
    WEIGHT=c(rnorm(100)*15+80),
    SEX=as.factor(sample(c("Male", "Female"), 100, replace=TRUE)),
    COLOR=as.factor(sample(c("Blue", "Green", "Pink", "Violet"), 100, replace=TRUE)),
    SOUND=as.factor(sample(c("Woof", "Meow", "Mooooooooo", "Quack"), 100, replace=TRUE))
    )
#
#   Functions for analyses within rtables based on 
#   https://rdrr.io/cran/rtables/f/vignettes/clinical_trials.Rmd
#
flexible_summary <- function(x) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    in_rows(
      "Mean (sd)" = rcell(c(mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)), format = "xx.xx (xx.xx)"),
      "min - max" = rcell(range(x, na.rm = TRUE), format = "xx.xx - xx.xx")
    )
  } else if (is.factor(x)) {
    vs <- as.list(table(x))
    do.call(in_rows, lapply(vs, rcell, format = "xx"))
  } else {
    stop("type not supported")
  }
}
#   Try to build empty table for continuous variables all at once:
#
lyt1 <- basic_table(show_colcounts = TRUE) %>%
  split_cols_by("TREATMENT") %>%
  analyze(vars = c("AGE", "HEIGHT", "WEIGHT", "SEX", "COLOR", "SOUND"), flexible_summary)
(Table1 <- build_table(lyt1, SubjChar))
```

This produced:

```
                   Drug A            Drug B            Placebo    
                   (N=34)            (N=37)            (N=29)     
——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
AGE                                                               
  Mean (sd)     31.46 (5.12)      29.88 (3.72)      30.61 (5.87)  
  min - max     21.70 - 43.21     21.56 - 37.81     20.71 - 39.90 
HEIGHT                                                            
  Mean (sd)    181.89 (23.66)    178.14 (21.15)    183.91 (18.54) 
  min - max    145.45 - 231.27   126.78 - 223.33   153.63 - 226.24
WEIGHT                                                            
  Mean (sd)     84.87 (15.21)     80.56 (13.20)     80.66 (13.90) 
  min - max    53.02 - 112.64    59.95 - 108.43    51.71 - 110.03 
SEX                                                               
  Female             16                19                17       
  Male               18                18                12       
COLOR                                                             
  Blue               12                12                 6       
  Green               8                 4                 7       
  Pink                7                11                11       
  Violet              7                10                 5       
SOUND                                                             
  Meow                6                 9                 8       
  Mooooooooo         13                 7                 8       
  Quack               9                10                 5       
  Woof                6                11                 8
```

What I would like would include percentages for categorical variables (SEX, COLOR, SOUND) as well as the various measures for continuous variables:

```
                   Drug A            Drug B            Placebo    
                   (N=34)            (N=37)            (N=29)     
——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
AGE                                                               
  Mean (sd)     31.46 (5.12)      29.88 (3.72)      30.61 (5.87)  
  min - max     21.70 - 43.21     21.56 - 37.81     20.71 - 39.90 
HEIGHT                                                            
  Mean (sd)    181.89 (23.66)    178.14 (21.15)    183.91 (18.54) 
  min - max    145.45 - 231.27   126.78 - 223.33   153.63 - 226.24
WEIGHT                                                            
  Mean (sd)     84.87 (15.21)     80.56 (13.20)     80.66 (13.90) 
  min - max    53.02 - 112.64    59.95 - 108.43    51.71 - 110.03   
SEX
      Female    16 (47.1%)      19 (51.4%)          17 (58.6%)
      Male      18 (52.9%)      18 (48.6%)          12 (41.4%)
COLOR
      Blue      12 (35.3%)      12 (32.4%)           6 (20.7%) 
      Green      8 (23.5%)       4 (10.8%)           7 (24.1%) 
      Pink       7 (20.6%)      11 (29.7%)          11 (37.9%)
      Violet     7 (20.6%)      10 (27.0%)           5 (17.2%) 
SOUND
      Meow       6 (17.6%)       9 (24.3%)           8 (27.6%) 
      Mooooooooo 13 (38.2%)      7 (18.9%)           8 (27.6%) 
      Quack       9 (26.5%)     10 (27.0%)           5 (17.2%) 
      Woof        6 (17.6%)     11 (29.7%)           8 (27.6%)
```

I tried analyzing a concatenation of these variables, but got all the levels collapsed:

```
lyt2 <- basic_table() %>%
  split_cols_by("TREATMENT") %>%
  analyze(vars = c("SEX", "COLOR", "HEIGHT"), Cat_Summary, format="xx (xx.x%)")
 (Table2 <- build_table(lyt2, SubjChar))
```

Yielding:

```
                 Drug A        Drug B        Placebo  
———————————————————————————————————————————————————————
SEX                                                    
  Cat_Summary   34 (100.0%)   37 (100.0%)   29 (100.0%)
COLOR                                                  
  Cat_Summary   34 (100.0%)   37 (100.0%)   29 (100.0%)
HEIGHT                                                 
  Cat_Summary   34 (100.0%)   37 (100.0%)   29 (100.0%)
```

I tried splitting rows by multiple variables:

```
lyt3 <- basic_table() %>%
  split_cols_by("TREATMENT") %>%
  split_rows_by( c("SEX", "COLOR", "HEIGHT"))
  analyze(vars = c("SEX", "COLOR", "HEIGHT"), Cat_Summary, format="xx (xx.x%)")
 (Table3 <- build_table(lyt3, SubjChar))
```

and got error about recursive indexing.  Next, I split then analyzed by each variable individually:

```
lyt4<- basic_table(show_colcounts = TRUE) %>%
    split_cols_by("TREATMENT") %>%  
    split_rows_by("SEX", indent_mod=3) %>%
    analyze("SEX", Cat_Summary, format=  "xx (xx.x%)") %>%
    split_rows_by("COLOR", indent_mod=3) %>%
    analyze("COLOR", Cat_Summary, format=  "xx (xx.x%)") %>%
    split_rows_by("SOUND", indent_mod=3) %>%
    analyze("SOUND", Cat_Summary, format=  "xx (xx.x%)") 
    
(Table4<-  build_table(lyt4 , SubjChar))
```

This gets closer, but all levels are listed from across the different variables and labeled with the function name:

```
                        Drug A       Drug B      Placebo  
                        (N=34)       (N=37)       (N=29)  
——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
      Female                                              
        Cat_Summary   16 (47.1%)   19 (51.4%)   17 (58.6%)
      Male                                                
        Cat_Summary   18 (52.9%)   18 (48.6%)   12 (41.4%)
      Blue                                                
        Cat_Summary   12 (35.3%)   12 (32.4%)   6 (20.7%) 
      Green                                               
        Cat_Summary   8 (23.5%)    4 (10.8%)    7 (24.1%) 
      Pink                                                
        Cat_Summary   7 (20.6%)    11 (29.7%)   11 (37.9%)
      Violet                                              
        Cat_Summary   7 (20.6%)    10 (27.0%)   5 (17.2%) 
      Meow                                                
        Cat_Summary   6 (17.6%)    9 (24.3%)    8 (27.6%) 
      Mooooooooo                                          
        Cat_Summary   13 (38.2%)   7 (18.9%)    8 (27.6%) 
      Quack                                               
        Cat_Summary   9 (26.5%)    10 (27.0%)   5 (17.2%) 
      Woof                                                
        Cat_Summary   6 (17.6%)    11 (29.7%)   8 (27.6%)
```

I expect I'm missing something that should be jumping out at me.  Thanks in advance for any help.